# Приближение и отдоление изображения

Tags: python

Я использую tkinter и pillow для отображения изображения. Но я думаю вообще без разници как реализовать приближение фото и его отдаление, а потом просто выводить результат. Или же кто-то может показать как реализовать лупу?

Comment: Приближение - кадрируете и растягиваете изображение. Уменьшение - просто уменьшаете.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну просто логично и понятно и без вашего ответа, только вот примера я так и не нашел в интернете. Везде одно это изменение размера изображения, но нигде нет увеличение и отдаление в указанной области например мышкой

Comment: А вот так например https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050687/8324991 Но интерфейс вам самому писать придётся думаю

Comment: Ну или вот с `tkinter` уже https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656176/tkinter-canvas-zoom-move-pan

Comment: Не нужно дублировать один и тот же вопрос. Достаточно отредактировать исходный вопрос, он снова поднимется на главной, его увидят больше людей.